# USB serial communication between Raspberry Pi 3 and Roboteq motor controller

Tags: pi-3, usb, serial, communication

I am new to Raspberry Pi and it's communication. I need to make a project where I want to use a Raspberry pi 3 as a monitoring device for motors and battery system. The Raspberry pi itself communicates with Roboteq controller using USB connection.
Below is the simple code I'm trying to send via USB to the motor controller. I want to get motor Amps and show values in the terminal:

```
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(

    port = '/dev/ttyACM0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout = 1
)

print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)

motor_AMPS = getvalue(_MOTAMPS)

print(motor_AMPS)
```

In the Roboteq user manual was written that by using `getvalue(_MOTAMPS)` command I can get motor amps. However when I am trying to run mention code the an error message is occur: `"module 'serial' has no attribute 'getvalue'"` It seems that I'm sending data to controller wrongly. I'havent found much info about Raspberry pi and Roboteq controller communication. So any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the manual online, can you provide a link to the command?

Comment: @CoderMike Yes, here it is: https://www.roboteq.com/index.php/docman/motor-controllers-documents-and-files/documentation/user-manual/272-roboteq-controllers-user-manual-v17/file
Section 15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to send a '?A [cc]' command then read the response.

Try the following:

```
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(

    port = '/dev/ttyACM0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout = 1
)

motorChannel = 1
command = '?A '+str(motorChannel)+' \r'
ser.write(command.encode())
data = ser.readline().decode().strip()
value = 0
if data.startswith('A='):
    value = int(data.split('=')[1])
print(value)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works fine. I get an output: `?A 1 A=0` However it seems, that the output is string. Is it possible to get output as int value so that it was possible to store it after and for example make comparisons with other variables

Comment: @ArtyomShep ["how to convert string to int in python?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071889/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-python)

Comment: Updated to extract int